# Calling a parent's function in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, parent

In Swift, I am trying to call a function on a node's parent, like this:

```
self.parent.unhighlightAllCheckers()
```

Didn't work. I think this is because the child node may not implicitly know what type of object the parent is, so I try an explicit cast:

```
let myParent: Gameboard = Gameboard(self.parent)
myParent.unhighlightAllCheckers()
```

Also doesn't work.  I am thinking this should be far simpler. How do you call a parent node's function?

Comment: Have you tried instead implementing a protocol for the child node class and making the parent the delegate.  You can then call that method in the parent node after it receives a message from the child's protocol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if let myParent = self.parent as? Gameboard {
    myParent.unhighlightAllCheckers()
}
```

<s>The explicit cast you have doesn't make sense as you're not using it in the next line.</s>

You're not casting you're actually creating a new Gameboard by calling the constructor. Casting would be using the as operator.

More importantly, when you do copy/cast/whatever be sure to use the variable you just created.

The if let ... as?  idiom in Swift is pretty great and there are more examples in the manual. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: **Important note:** His example is not using "explicit casting" or any "casting" at all. He is making a **copy**

Answer (score 4):

It is very important to realize that

```
let myParent: Gameboard = Gameboard(self.parent)
```

is not "casting". You are initializing an entirely new variable that is based on `self.parent`. This is much closer to "copying" than anything else.

In Swift, you cast using the `as` operator. There is also an optional cast operator `as?`. `as` will crash the program if the casting is not successful while `as?` will return `nil` if not successful.

`as` example:

```
(self.parent as GameBoard).unhighlightAllCheckers()
```

`as?` example:

```
(self.parent as? GameBoard)?.unhighlightAllCheckers()
```

**Note:** I added a `?` after the casting to make use of [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_352) to only call `unhighlightAllCheckers` if the casting does not return nil.

If you need to use self.parent as a Gameboard for multiple calls, you can use a temporary variable with [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_476):

```
if let myParent = self.parent as? Gameboard {
    myParent.unhighlightAllCheckers()
}
```